# How do you use eyed3 to create comments for MP3 files?

Tags: python, metadata, comments, mp3, eyed3

I made a script that changes some metadata of MP3 files to title case, while wiping all other fields. It does this by copying the existing metadata to a separate variable, then wiping the original data with tag.clear(), and finally adding back the metadata now in title case. This works for every tag I've used, except comments.

When there are existing comments, I can edit them with this:

```
import eyed3
mp3 = eyed3.load(FILE_PATH)
comments = mp3.tag.comments
comments_list = []
for comment in comments:
comments_list.append(comment.text.title()) #This creates an editable list for recall
for comment in comments: #As long as there were already comments, I can change them with this:
comment.text = ("anything")
mp3.tag.save()
```

However, as a result of clearing all metadata, comments only returns None, and the previous code won't work. How can I add comments?
It looks like this:
[Comments blank, but everything else works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40hOX.png)

To clarify, I want to add comments to a blank MP3 file. I already know how to edit existing comments, as shown by the block of code above.

When I looked up how comments work in Eyed3, all I found was "the comments attribute is an instance of the CommentsAccessor class, and it doesn't have a direct text attribute". That's why I can't just get the comment in the same way I might get the title:
title = audiofile.tag.title

It also means I can't set it the same way, and that's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Are you trying to add something to existing comments? Are you trying to replace them? I don't understand the point of comments_list in your code. If you could clarify the question, it would be easier to provide help.

Comment: To clarify, I want to add comments to a blank MP3 file.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I'm not clear what your code is trying to achieve (e.g., if the file metadata is blank, what are you trying to append into the `comments_list` and why?).

But in any case, the following code should add a general comment to your file.

```
comment_to_add = "My new comment" # Change this to the comment you want

import eyed3

mp3 = eyed3.load(FILE_PATH)
mp3.tag.clear()

comments = mp3.tag.comments
comments.set(comment_to_add)

mp3.tag.save()
```

It's also unclear what the intention is with the *For* loop. It's possible to add comments under different keys/descriptions in the following format

```
comments.set(TEXT, DESCRIPTION)
```

in which case, the *For* loop would iterate over those. For example,

```
comment_to_add = "My new comment"

import eyed3

mp3 = eyed3.load(FILE_PATH)
mp3.tag.clear()

comments = mp3.tag.comments

comments.set(comment_to_add)
comments.set("Classical", "Genre")
comments.set("1824", "year")

mp3.tag.save()

"""The code below should return:
My new comment
Classical
1824
"""
for c in comments:
    print(c.text)
```

The changes should appear in the file (MediaInfo output below):

```
'''
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 153 KiB
Duration                                 : 8 s 620 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 kb/s
Genre                                    : Classical
Writing library                          : LAME3.90 (alpha)
Comment                                  : My new comment
year                                     : 1824
'''
```

Comment: The for loop is due to comments being saved as a list, and I'm saving each comment to another list so I can use them after the data wipe.

Your first suggestion is what I'm looking for, but when I tried your code to create a general comment, but it was still left blank.

Comment: That's strange because the code should be OK. Could you add some details about your setup in the question? How are you checking the result (that the comment is blank)?

Comment: I tried your code merged with mine, but when it didn't work, I tried your code alone (only changing FILE_PATH) and it still returned None. I am checking by looking at the file itself (which becomes blank), as well as trying to edit the comment using the block of code in my first post. It returns an error for using None type incorrectly.

Comment: I meant how are you looking at the file? For example, I've used mediainfo, which returned the info in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I check the actual file in Windows File Explorer, and again using the terminal itself. In both cases, the comments section is blank.

Comment: Not sure how reliable Win File Explorer would be, but can't think of anything else to try for troubleshooting without exchanging the MP3 file in question. Not sure how to do this on SO.

Comment: The problem is that comments are registered in a different format, and handled differently from the other tags, but the documentation is unclear how to create the comment object.

Comment: What do you mean "registered in a different format"? Please add more information about the problems you're seeing in the original question if you have it.